# Shopping List Program

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am coding a program that simulates someone making a purchase in a grocery store. I am displaying all the products and the price and I am prompting the user to input all the products they went to buy separated by commas. I want the program to check if the input is in the dictionary of product and add it to the cart with the use of a loop. Before adding it to cart the program needs to check if the input is valid, meaning if the item is in the list of products to buy. When the user selects an item to buy, I want the program to ask the user for the quantity of that item, so how many of the item they want to buy. At the samThen the program will calculate the total of all the products, then calculate the tax value, 24% of the total, and then return a subtotal that includes tax. Here is what I have so far:

```
def calculatetotal(slist, produce):
    # for each item on the shoping list look up the cost & calculate total price
    item_price = 0
    subtotal = 0
    VAT = 0
    final_total = 0
    basket = {}
    for item in slist:
        item_price = produce.get(item)
        basket[item] = item_price
        subtotal = subtotal + item_price

    basket["Subtotal"] = subtotal

    #calculating VAT
    VAT = subtotal * 0.24
    basket["VAT"] = VAT

    #calculating price with tax
    final_total = subtotal + VAT
    basket["Total"] = final_total

    # print off results
    return basket


def main():
    # set up grocery list with prices
    produce={"Rice":5.00, "Bread":2.00, "Sugar":1.5, "Apple":0.75, "Cereal":3.75, "Gum": 1.00, "Water": 1.75, "Soda": 2.00}
    # process input from the user - get a shopping list
    item = input("Please enter the items that you want to buy: ")
    slist = []
    while(item != 'stop'):
        if not (item in slist):
            slist.append(item)
            item = input("Please enter the items that you want to buy: ")
        
    result = calculatetotal(slist, produce)
    print(result)

main()
```

I've gotten most of it, but the small changes that I mentioned above, I can't figure out what to do. I forgot to mention that asking for the quantity of the item and checking if the user input has to be done with a loop. Any input is very much appreciated. Please show the change of code. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case I would simply go for a while loop

```
while True:
    item = input("Please enter the items that you want to buy: ")
    if item == 'Stop':
        break
    elif item not in produce or item in slist:
        # error message or whatever
    else:
        num = int(input("Enter Quantity"))
        # other operations
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. What would I need to add to this for the program to check if the input for items is numeric. If the user puts a number I want it to say only letters

Comment: this would typically be what we call input validation, try googling 'input validation python'  :)

Comment: I'd like to rephrase my original question. I want to verify if the item that the user inputted is in the list of items. If it is not, then print a message saying "The item is not in the list, enter another input"

Comment: That is the reason why I have the condition `elif item not in produce`, it is exactly checking for what you said.

Comment: If you find the solution useful please accept the answer, thanks!